# How to hide FBLoginView if user is loggedin?

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoa-touch, facebook-graph-api

By default, FBLoginView displays "Login" or "Logout" if the user is authenticated or not;

I want to hide FBLoginView if the user is authenticated. How can I do that? How can I check if the user is authenticated or not authenticated?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
Before moving the frame you should try doing either:

```
loginview.hidden = YES;
```

or

```
[loginview setHidden:YES];
```

Working off the HelloFacebookSample, you can simply move the FBLoginView frame off the screen.  The delegate methods will fire if the user changes from logged in to logged out (and vice versa).

```
- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
    // first get the buttons set for login mode
    NSLog(@"FB logged in - token expiration: %@",[[FBSession activeSession] accessTokenData].expirationDate);

    //User logged in. Move FBLoginView off the screen
    loginview.frame = CGRectOffset(loginview.frame, 5, -100);

    self.buttonPostPhoto.enabled = YES;
    self.buttonPostStatus.enabled = YES;
    self.buttonPickFriends.enabled = YES;
    self.buttonPickPlace.enabled = YES;

    // "Post Status" available when logged on and potentially when logged off.  Differentiate in the label.
    [self.buttonPostStatus setTitle:@"Post Status Update (Logged On)" forState:self.buttonPostStatus.state];
}

- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {

    //User logged off. Move FBLoginView back within view
    loginview.frame = CGRectOffset(loginview.frame, 5, 5);    // test to see if we can use the share dialog built into the Facebook application

    FBShareDialogParams *p = [[FBShareDialogParams alloc] init];
    p.link = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://developers.facebook.com/ios"];
#ifdef DEBUG
    [FBSettings enableBetaFeatures:FBBetaFeaturesShareDialog];
#endif
    BOOL canShareFB = [FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams:p];
    BOOL canShareiOS6 = [FBDialogs canPresentOSIntegratedShareDialogWithSession:nil];

    self.buttonPostStatus.enabled = canShareFB || canShareiOS6;
    self.buttonPostPhoto.enabled = NO;
    self.buttonPickFriends.enabled = NO;
    self.buttonPickPlace.enabled = NO;

    // "Post Status" available when logged on and potentially when logged off.  Differentiate in the label.
    [self.buttonPostStatus setTitle:@"Post Status Update (Logged Off)" forState:self.buttonPostStatus.state];

    self.profilePic.profileID = nil;
    self.labelFirstName.text = nil;
    self.loggedInUser = nil;
}
```

In this example, you would have to declare `FBLoginView *loginview` in your header file.